# Lug for 250mcm neutral wire in Siemens panel

Tags: electrical-panel, neutral

I'm pulling feeders for an outbuilding 350' away.  To keep the voltage drop down, I'm using 250mcm wire (150amp service).  My question is what's the best way to land the neutral wire to the panel?  It's a Siemens PN series 200 amp panel; it looks like the ECLK2 neutral lug supports up to 2/0 wire.  Does the ECLK3 work somehow?  An ugly method would be to splice the 250mcm back to 2/0 before the lug in the same panel using a Polaris connector, but I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: Which model specifically? I took a look at the PN4040B-L1200C-W and the spec sheet shows that the neutral can take up to 300 mcm, with no distinction made Cu or Al. Also have you already bought the 250 mcm feeder? 4/0 is totally compatible with that same panel with no changes, and at 150 amps you're talking 2.8% vs 3.2% voltage drop which is pretty trivial.

Comment: And by compatible I mean it will go in to the mains, which have a 4/0 size limit unless you change out the main breaker for one that can take bigger wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use an ECLK3N

According to [Siemens' accessory guide for PN and SN panels](https://pdf.lowes.com/productdocuments/676a2649-95c0-4470-8bb2-acd7223aabde/49975858.pdf), all 150A Siemens PN and SN panels save for the {P/S}NW0816BxxxT[C] feed-through ("ranch") panels can accept the ECLK3N lug kit, which is rated for wires up to 300kcmil.